# Find $A$ that solves $(X^i B - B A^i )Y$ for all $i$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Consider the following matrix equation for $A$:
$$\left[\underbrace{X^{i}}_{2\times2}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\underbrace{A^{i}}_{4\times4} \right]\underbrace{Y}_{4\times3}=0\quad \forall i\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}$$ for some given $X,Y$. The dimensions of $A,X,Y$ are indicated underneath the braces.

Note that there always exists a trivial solution: $$A=\begin{pmatrix}X_{11} & X_{12} & 0 & 0\\
X_{21} & X_{22} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I have two questions:

1. Will there always be other solutions, regardless of $Y$?
2. Can one characterize the complete set of solutions for $A$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$ without referring to $i$?. E.g., are there necessary and sufficient conditions on $A$ which can be checked using $X$ and $Y$ (but not $i$)?

Comment: Note that your constant matrix picks out the first two rows of whatever is to its right.

Comment: I know, but I am not sure how to use it since it's premultiplying different terms on both sides. In a way it is precisely the constant matrix what makes the problem difficult:

Comment: If it weren't for the constant matrix (i.e., if we had $X^i Y = A^i Y$ with $A,X,Y$ being $2\times 2$), then things would be simple and we could always set $A=X$.